# Can anyone tell me how to rectify this error in aws server

Tags: magento-2.1, php, aws

[image]

Can anyone tell me how to rectify this error in aws server. How to increase php verson in aws server

Comment: you need to install the right version of PHP. Magento2 supports 7.0.2. Try to install the same version on the server. Once the PHP version is resolved, then you easily install the missing extensions. Are you using bitnami package?

Comment: do you have any idea about how to update php verson in aws server

Answer (score 0):

I m considering that you are on centos/redhat.

1. For no glitches in future, frst you need uninstall the existing PHP version in your machine.
2. Restart the machine.
3. Update the REPO to the latest with the below code. (if ur's is centos7 )

   rpm -Uvh https://mirror.webtatic.com/yum/el7/webtatic-release.rpm
4. Now run `yum install php`.

You can follow the below link for more information.

http://www.2daygeek.com/install-php-7-on-ubuntu-centos-debian-fedora-mint-rhel-opensuse/#